# What is the best way to have output of multiple commands in one console?

Tags: command-line, bash, grunt

I working to improve my programming environment and now I need to have output of multiple commands (coffeescript/sass compilation and unit tests) in one console. This can be achieve concatenating commands with `&`:

```
karma start & coffee -o js/app -cw coffee/ & sass --watch sass/:css/
```

but when I would like to finish work and close them and press `ctrl+c` they will still work in background and I have to kill each of them manually. How can I fix this and have ability to close all those commands at once?

Currently I can only think of making a [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) task that will run multiple commands but using grunt seems to be an overkill for such a task. Are there easier/alternative ways?

Comment: Is it necessary to run the commands in the background via `&`?

Comment: You ask two questions at once. One in the title and one in the text. What's your goal?

Comment: @A.B. I don't care where and how commands will run - I need them to run at the same time, see their output in singe console and ability to kill all of them at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: You can only Display one program/task at once. Also, some programs like `apt-get` don't work properly this way.)

---

First, add an `&` symbol to the end of the line, so the line looks like this:

```
karma start & coffee -o js/app -cw coffee/ & sass --watch sass/:css/ &
```

That puts the last program in the background too.

---

Then, type in `jobs` to list the programs. You'll then have an output that somewhat resembles this:

```
karma start [1]
coffee -o js/app -cw coffee/ [2]
sass --watch sass/:css/ [3]
```

To bring a program to the foreground, type `fg` followed by the number of the program. For example, to bring `karma start` to the foreground, type `fg 1`. To put it back in the background, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. Repeat as required.

Comment: for me it's not a `job` but `jobs`

Answer (score 1):

Just kill the terminal...  That'll kill all commands it's running, unless you take special precautions like `dtach`...

Comment: simple and obvious solution, thanx )

Comment: @SET: and the most upvoted one!  (so the best!)  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `job` to list your command, you will have something like this

```
karma start [1]
coffee -o js/app -cw coffee/ [2]
```

Use `fg 1` or `fg 2` to bring back jobs in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

`&` doesn't concatenate commands. It start one by one in the background. If it's not necessary to start the commands in the background, simply use `;` instead of `&`.

Comment: `;` will wait for command to end, but OP want to run all command at once.